# Where are docs for symfony4 without flex?

Tags: symfony

Symfony 4 docs keep giving examples using flex, but say flex is optional.

Where are the getting started / upgrade docs for symfony 4 w/o flex?

https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html for example says it is optional.

My corp proxy blocks symfony.sh so flex does not work, and I have no hope of getting it unblocked.

Comment: or posed another way, "how can I use symfony 4 without flex?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically said, you will just update the `symfony/symfony` package like you did before when updating to a new version of Symfony. You *could* stop depending on `symfony/symfony` and pull in all the needed components manually, but personally I would not mess with that if you cannot use Flex because of the overhead you have to do manually that would have been done by Flex instead.

For now, you then need to ignore the additional instructions in the documentation that explain which Symfony component you need to install (because you have them all thanks to the `symfony/symfony` package).

You can then make use of the additional config files that are used in a Flex application (basically `config/packages/*`), but in this case you would need to ensure that all these files are loaded in your application (you can compare the default kernel of a Flex application with your kernel class). The easier part would probably be to just place config options in the `config*.yml` files you are already used to.